# Need data from mysql to draw graph

Tags: php, mysql, pie-chart

I want to draw a graph where value will be taken from MySQL database. it is not working. But if I give the manual value then the graph is showing. Below is my code:

```
<?php
include "libchart/classes/libchart.php";

header("Content-type: image/png");

$chart = new LineChart();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bkash");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT time,trx_value FROM dialer_rate where mno='tnr'"); 
$serie1 = new XYDataSet();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
$serie1->addPoint(new Point($row['time']->time, $row['trx_value']->trx_value));
  }

$dataSet = new XYSeriesDataSet();
$dataSet->addSerie("TNR", $serie1);
$dataSet->addSerie("ROBI", $serie2);
$dataSet->addSerie("LNK", $serie3);
$dataSet->addSerie("AIR", $serie4);
$chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

$chart->setTitle("bKash Success/Failure for All MNO");
$chart->getPlot()->setGraphCaptionRatio(0.62);

$chart->render();
```

?>

i am not getting any value in time & trx_value in below line...

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
$serie1->addPoint(new Point($row['time']->time, $row['trx_value']->trx_value));
  }
```

but if i want to print the value using echo below output comes

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  { echo $row['time'];
    echo $row['trx_value'];
  };
```

Then output is coming..

also graph is showing when i am using manual value like below.

```
$serie1->addPoint(new Point("06-01", 273));
$serie1->addPoint(new Point("06-02", 421));
$serie1->addPoint(new Point("06-03", 642));
$serie1->addPoint(new Point("06-04", 799));
$serie1->addPoint(new Point("06-05", 1009));
$serie1->addPoint(new Point("06-06", 1106));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got quotes around `$row['time']->time` that shouldn't be there, and it looks like you're trying to "double-index" your columns (i.e. get values using both `['field']` and `->field`).

```
new Point("$row['time']->time", $row['trx_value']->trx_value)
```

should probably be

```
new Point($row['time'], $row['trx_value'])
```

Notice how Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter suggests the first issue. If your text editor doesn't support syntax highlighting, it might be worthwhile to switch to one that does.

Comment: @Basudev, are you sure that `$row['time']` and `$row['trx_value']` contain what you think they do? `echo` them out, or use `var_dump()` on `$row`.

Comment: Yes, my data is in 'time' and 'trx_value' column.

Comment: @Basudev, then you probably don't need `->time` and `->trx_value`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Basudev, okay, you *really* need to `var_dump($row)`. We need to see what's inside that variable. Please edit your question and add that output.

Comment: if i print using echo then value is showing
 echo $row['time'];
but below is not working
$serie1->addPoint(new Point($row['time'], $row['trx_value']));

Comment: @Basudev, twice you have told me what you *think* a variable contains. Please copy the *actual output* to your question. Use the "edit" link at the bottom left of the question. If you don't do this it is unlikely that we'll be able to help you.